# ExoPlayer audio starts before video

Tags: android, audio, video, synchronization, exoplayer

We are having problems about the player.

We only play mp4 files.

When there is low internet connection, audio starts before the video and the video starts playing after 2-3 seconds. There is no synchronization problem meaning when video appears the audio and video synchronized. But there is a latency with the video.

What can we do about this?

Comment: I am having the same issue after the video resumes after home button is pressed. Did you find any solution @Cem Kacmaz?

Comment: Hi Sammy. You can see the details from here https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/595 . The issue added as bug. But there was also a problem with my stream (audio and video was not evenly interleaved).

Comment: Experiencing this bug on Exoplayer 2.17.1 on local file uri